# UnitTest failing only when all tests get executed at once

Tags: c++, unit-testing, binary-search-tree

I'm currently facing an odd problem when running a Microsoft C++ `UnitTest` within VS2013.

The test is failing each time I execute `Run All` tests in the IDE, but when I use `Run Selected Tests` on the specific one, it succeeds.

What I'm testing for is the usage of my own `BinarySearchTree` class. In case of failure, the exception code `C0000005` gets returned (this may be due to wrong internal linkage of pointers).

So what can be the reason for this?

#### Additional

The test is failing on this last piece of code, where I generate random ID strings, add them individually to my `BST` and remove them randomly till the whole `BST` is empty again.

```
BinarySearchTree clientList;
Client client;

// test random adding & deletion
std::vector<std::string> idAddList;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    idAddList.push_back(randomID(20));

std::vector<std::string> idRemoveList;
unsigned int id;
while (idAddList.size() > 0)
{
    // pick random id from list and delete it
    id = rand() % idAddList.size();
    client.uniqueID = idAddList.at(id);
    clientList.add(client);
    if (clientList.lastICLResult() == iList::ICLResult::OK)
        idRemoveList.push_back(idAddList.at(id));
    idAddList.erase(idAddList.begin() + id);
}

    while (idRemoveList.size() > 0)
{
    // pick random client from list and delete it
    id = rand() % idRemoveList.size();
    clientList.remove(idRemoveList.at(id));
    if (clientList.lastICLResult() == iList::ICLResult::OK)
        idRemoveList.erase(idRemoveList.begin() + id);
}

Assert::AreEqual<unsigned int>(0, clientList.size());
```

Here the code for the `randomID()` function:

```
std::string randomID(const unsigned int maxLength)
{
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "öÖäÄüÜ"
        "!=[]$%&";

    std::string result;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        result += alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum - 1))];

    return result;
}
```

Relevant class-specific code to this problem would be the `removeMatch()` function and the according `Node` class. The `BST` takes a `Client` class as data object for its `add()` function and only adds the given client if its ID string isn't already in the `BST`. Internal there are also the functions `fetchMinNode()` and `fetchMaxNode()`, that either retrieve a pointer to the left-most or right-most node in the `BST`. The main/root node is called `m_rootNode`, that get's assigned a `nullptr` if the `BST` gets empty.

In case of the `removeMatch()` function, I always go for the right child node/subtree of the to be deleted node, and - if possible - reassign the internal node tree on the specific place.

```
void iList::removeMatch(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    if (toBeDeletedNode)
    {
        // IN CASE GIVEN NODE IS THE ROOT NODE
        if (!toBeDeletedNode->parent)
        {
            // Case 1: root node is the only node in the BST
            if (!toBeDeletedNode->left && !toBeDeletedNode->right)
                handleRootLeaf(toBeDeletedNode);

            // Case 2: either both child nodes are available or just the right
            //         child node is available
            else if ((toBeDeletedNode->left && toBeDeletedNode->right) || toBeDeletedNode->right)
                handleRootRSubtree(toBeDeletedNode);

            // Case 3: only left child node is present
            else
                handleRootLSubtree(toBeDeletedNode);
        }

        // IN CASE GIVEN NODE IS ANY CHILD NODE
        else
        {
            // Case 1: if given node is a leaf node
            if (!toBeDeletedNode->left && !toBeDeletedNode->right)
                handleChildLeaf(toBeDeletedNode);

            // Case 2: if given node has either both child nodes or just a right child node
            else if ((toBeDeletedNode->left && toBeDeletedNode->right) || toBeDeletedNode->right)
                handleChildRSubtree(toBeDeletedNode);

            // Case 3: if given node has only a left child node
            else
                handleChildLSubtree(toBeDeletedNode);
        }

        m_elementCount--;
    }
}
```

#### And here the according private functions:

[private] `handleRootLSubtree()`

```
void handleRootLSubtree(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    // fetch max node in left subtree
    Node* maxNode = fetchMaxNode(toBeDeletedNode->left);

    // in case left child node is the max node
    if (maxNode->parent != toBeDeletedNode)
    {
        if (maxNode->left)
        {
            maxNode->left->parent = maxNode->parent;
            maxNode->parent->right = maxNode->left;
        }
        else
            maxNode->parent->right = nullptr;

        maxNode->left = toBeDeletedNode->left;
        maxNode->parent->parent = maxNode;
    }

    maxNode->parent = nullptr;

    // cut linkage
    toBeDeletedNode->left = nullptr;
    delete toBeDeletedNode;
    m_rootNode = maxNode;
}
```

[private] `handleRootRSubtree()`

```
void handleRootRSubtree(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    // fetch min node in right subtree
    Node* minNode = fetchMinNode(toBeDeletedNode->right);

    // in case right child node isn't the min node
    if (minNode->parent != toBeDeletedNode)
    {
        if (minNode->right)
        {
            minNode->right->parent = minNode->parent;
            minNode->parent->left = minNode->right;
        }
        else
            minNode->parent->left = nullptr;

        minNode->right = toBeDeletedNode->right;
        toBeDeletedNode->right->parent = minNode;
    }

    minNode->left = toBeDeletedNode->left;
    minNode->parent = nullptr;

    if (toBeDeletedNode->left)
        toBeDeletedNode->left->parent = minNode;

    // cut linkage
    toBeDeletedNode->left = nullptr;
    toBeDeletedNode->right = nullptr;
    delete toBeDeletedNode;
    m_rootNode = minNode;
}
```

[private] `handleRootLeaf()`

```
void handleRootLeaf(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    delete m_rootNode;
    m_rootNode = nullptr;
}
```

[private] `handleChildLSubtree()`

```
void handleChildLSubtree(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    // fetch max node in left subtree
    Node* maxNode = fetchMaxNode(toBeDeletedNode->left);

    // in case left child node is the max node
    if (maxNode->parent == toBeDeletedNode)
        maxNode->parent = toBeDeletedNode->parent;
    else
    {
        if (maxNode->left)
        {
            maxNode->left->parent = maxNode->parent;
            maxNode->parent->right = maxNode->left;
        }
        else
            maxNode->parent->right = nullptr;

        maxNode->left = toBeDeletedNode->left;
        toBeDeletedNode->left->parent = maxNode;
        maxNode->parent = toBeDeletedNode->parent;
    }

    if (toBeDeletedNode->parent->left
        && toBeDeletedNode->parent->left == toBeDeletedNode)
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->left = maxNode;
    else
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->right = maxNode;

    // cut linkage
    toBeDeletedNode->left = nullptr;
    toBeDeletedNode->right = nullptr;
    delete toBeDeletedNode;
}
```

[private] `handleChildRSubtree()`

```
void handleChildRSubtree(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    // fetch min node in right subtree
    Node* minNode = fetchMinNode(toBeDeletedNode->right);

    // in case right child node is the min node
    if (minNode->parent == toBeDeletedNode)
    {
        if (toBeDeletedNode->left)
        {
            minNode->left = toBeDeletedNode->left;
            toBeDeletedNode->left->parent = minNode;
        }
        minNode->parent = toBeDeletedNode->parent;
    }
    else
    {
        if (minNode->right)
        {
            minNode->right->parent = minNode->parent;
            minNode->parent->left = minNode->right;
        }
        else
            minNode->parent->left = nullptr;

        minNode->left = toBeDeletedNode->left;
        if (toBeDeletedNode->left)
            toBeDeletedNode->left->parent = minNode;
        minNode->right = toBeDeletedNode->right;
        toBeDeletedNode->right->parent = minNode;
        minNode->parent = toBeDeletedNode->parent;
    }

    if (toBeDeletedNode->parent->left
        && toBeDeletedNode->parent->left == toBeDeletedNode)
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->left = minNode;
    else
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->right = minNode;

    // cut linkage
    toBeDeletedNode->left = nullptr;
    toBeDeletedNode->right = nullptr;
    delete toBeDeletedNode;
}
```

[private] `handleChildLeaf()`

```
void handleChildLeaf(Node* toBeDeletedNode)
{
    if (toBeDeletedNode->parent->left
        && toBeDeletedNode->parent->left == toBeDeletedNode)
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->left = nullptr;
    else
        toBeDeletedNode->parent->right = nullptr;
    delete toBeDeletedNode;
}
```

`Node` class:

```
struct Node
{
    Node() : client(nullptr), parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    ~Node();
    Client* client;
    Node*   parent;
    Node*   left;
    Node*   right;
};
```

Comment: Test class setup and test class teardown would also be useful to see.

Comment: `Relevant class-specific code to this problem would be the remove() function` So where is the code?

Comment: Fails on run all but works on run specific test roots are usually caused by your tests not resetting the environment correctly, often caused by mocks or global/static variables. Sometimes running tests in groups can help to narrow down the tests interacting with each other and hence the one that is causing the problem (it is often but the test that actually fails)

Comment: @AndyG sry. it's the `removeMatch()` function

Comment: Spaghetti code tested with spaghetti unit-test code - I give up. Consider writing smaller methods that do one thing only, with smaller unit-tests that test one thing only.

Comment: You should show code, but not that much code.

Comment: @BartoszKP so how exactly should I split up the remove function for deleting a specific node in the BST in your opinion? the `removeMatch()` function is handling all needed use-cases darn good. And why spaghetti code?

Comment: @neuronal.bit It's far from "darn good" because of exactly that reason - it shouldn't handle all needed cases. It should delegate each case to a smaller method dedicated to this case. Each of these methods should also use a bunch of smaller methods, of which some will be shared. Which will additionally eliminate code duplication in the current version of `removeMatch`.

Comment: @BartoszKP any advice in what functions to implement for `removeMatch` in order to reduce the so called spaghetti code?

Comment: @neuronal.bit: Then what does `clientList.remove(idRemoveList.at(id));` do?

Comment: @AndyG why is this still necessary for you to know?, this thread is as good as closed. my spaghetti code doesn't fit the need :D anyway, all this method does is looking for the specific string ID in the `BST`, if its found, the `removeMatch()` function gets called.

Comment: @forsvarir i moved the failing unit code sample to an own `TEST_METHOD` in order to have a fresh environment, but the same problem still occurs.

Comment: @neuronal.bit Start with every piece of duplicated code. Then move each `if`/`else if`/`else` into a separate method.

Comment: @BartoszKP well here you go, hope know it's a bit clearer.

Comment: @neuronal.bit Definitely looks better. If you'll do the same with your unit tests, and make them independent you should quickly identify the problem :)

Comment: @BartoszKP already done, guess what, now i got one more failing unit test, yay

Comment: @neuronal.bit That's good - it helped you in identifying yet another problem. And if this test has smaller scope this identification should be more helpful then the initial failure. Just keep segmenting/extracting until tests/functions will be small and easy to comprehend. The issue will reveal itself ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP thanks for your tips, helped me a lot, could narrow down the problem easily and could fix error within 10min. :) one last thing. since these new `handle...` functions are specifically for `removeMatch()`, what naming convention could I use to avoid using them accidentally later while implementing new stuff?

Comment: @neuronal.bit If they have good names it should be hard to use them by accident. Also, the principle of small, easy to understand pieces of code applies to classes as well. Cheers and good luck! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of error lies within the `handleRootLSubtree()` function:

The line

> maxNode->parent->parent = maxNode;

has to be replaced with

> toBeDeletedNode->left->parent = maxNode;